# How to transfer method call to another thread with some short code?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I have a Gui class that is supposed to update GUI, which runs in Swing main thread and must be accessed from that thread. I have some methods to change what is displayed in Gui. Some of those methods may be called from other threads. I ended up with this code:

```
   public void changeSomethingInGui() {
     change button enabled state for example...
   }
   public void changeSomethingInGuiAsync() {
     SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
         Gui.this.changeSomethingInGui();
       }
     });
   }
```

This really sucks, there's like 5 more similar methods and this strategy will require many lines of totally useless (for the reader) code.

There's no worst way of handling callback than the java's, that's for sure, but isn't there some workaround? For example in C++, I can post methods as callbacks to threads like this (using boost library):

```
guiThreadClass.queueAction(boost::bind(Gui::DoSomethingInGui, guiInstance, param1, param2));
```

One single line. That would make it 3 lines for every method in my class - much more comfortable.

Comment: Looks like insignificantly shorter version of the anonymous class. Is this the best I can get? Isn't my design flawed?

Comment: Your design is the proper way to handle GUI call in Java. While Lambda can be much shorter than your posted code. Like

SwingUtilities.invokeLater( () -> Gui.this.changeSomethingInGui() );

Comment: @AlexSuo Ok if that is true, I underestimated lambdas a lot!

Comment: Java 8 supports method references: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html which is basically like your C++ example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [Java 8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/), given this method

```
public void changeSomethingInGui() {
    //change button enabled state for example...
}
```

you can replace this invocation

```
public void changeSomethingInGuiAsync() {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Gui.this.changeSomethingInGui();
        }
    });
}
```

with a [*lambda expression*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html)

```
public void changeSomethingInGuiAsync() {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
        Gui.this.changeSomethingInGui();
    });
}
```

or a [*method reference*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html)

```
public void changeSomethingInGuiAsync() {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(Gui.this::changeSomethingInGui);
}
```

Additional recent examples may be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3A230513%20EventQueue.invokeLater).